# System.Xml.XmlException occurred. Name cannot begin with the 'Ｇ' character, hexadecimal value 0xFF27. Line 44, position 4

Tags: c#, xml, utf-16

I have written a code to read an xml file which contains Japanese characters.
Code written to read the xml file is:

```
        DataSet xmlData = new DataSet();            
        xmlData.ReadXml("c:\\abc.xml");
```

But while executing this code an exception 'System.Xml.XmlException' is occurring since the xml file contains an English character 'G' Line 44.

the Error message shown is: ="Name cannot begin with the 'Ｇ' character, hexadecimal value 0xFF27. Line 44, position 4."

How can I solve this.??
My xml file details including encoding description are given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?>
```

Thanks in Advance,
Bijoy.

Comment: can you show the XML, particularly around line 44 ?

Comment: <Ｇ_Ｌカテゴリー>DBN</Ｇ_Ｌカテゴリー> this is the content at Line 44

Comment: in XML tag names should contain only ASCII characters.

Answer (score 3):

That's a [FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff27/index.htm), not a normal letter.

Replace it with a normal `G`.

Comment: This xml file is supplied by the End User. we are not supposed to edit. Can we read this by using any other encoding schemes..?

Comment: @bjoy: You can't.  It's illegal XML.   Just like you can't parse `<></>`, you also can't parse `<Ｇ></Ｇ>`.

Comment: You could loop through the characters and replace fullwidth ones with normal ASCII by subtracting `0xFFE0` if it's between `0xFF21` and `0xFF5A`.

Comment: @bjoy, you are saying that you have to read it at all cost, then you should roll your own format parser as what you have is not XML. In XML tag names should contain only ASCII characters and any decent XML parser will choke on this.

Comment: @Darin: Actually, [that's not true anymore](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets).  However, [when .Net's XML parser was written, it was](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#CharClasses).

Comment: This Wikipedia (yeah I know) page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_Characters_in_XML suggests these characters are legal, doesn't it?

Comment: @Aakash: [When .Net's XML parser was written, they were illegal](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#CharClasses).

Comment: Oh right, I see, didn't grasp the context of the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

0xFF27 is full-width Latin letter 'G', which is not the same as Latin letter 'G'. You should use latin letters (in ASCII range) instead of full-width letters (in range FF01-FF5E). If XML is not too large the just use english keyboard and replace all letters, one by one.